# Sending a byte stream from a java program to a device running C

Tags: java, endianness

I am working with a device that supports little endian byte order. How do I do this in Java?

I have created a byte stream from the hex data and wrote it to the socket output stream. I am supposed to send data in the following format.

> Protocol-Version: 0x0001
>
> Request_Code: 0x0011
>
> Request_Size: 0x00000008

```
String s = "0001001100000008";
byte[] bytes = hexStringToByteArray(s);
socket.getOutputStream().write(bytes);

public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
            + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

I am however not receiving any response from the device for this request. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you debug your program on the C-end, what data does it receive for the protocol version, request code, and request size?

Comment: Just to be clear: you appear to be sending *character data*, not numbers in "binary", so the need for "little endian" is not clear.  Can you verify what you are supposed to send?  Is it ASCII/UTF-8 or do you need to actually send the data as binary words?

Comment: I am not debugging on the C end. I don't have access to it.

Comment: You need to debug on the server.  Can you set up a test server that duplicates the code from the server?

Comment: Hey @markspace I'm new to this so i'm not sure. The document says "All data
transmitted over the Ipv4-1 communication protocol is in Little Endian (Intel) byte order". I think I have to send the hex data as a byte array in little endian.

Comment: @markspace I do not have the server code just this description that was given to me by the manufacturer.

Comment: Well without access to the server and its code, it's hard to say.  The protocol description is a little unclear.  If its binary, you are sending in big endian.  Take a look at `ByteBuffer`, which has a byte order [you can set.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html)

Comment: @SagarNair: Since the protocol includes a "request size" field, you might want to make sure that the request you're sending has the size you are saying it does. If that request size is intended to be in bytes (which seems a reasonable interpretation), you should make sure you're writing that many bytes (likely not counting the header bytes of the protocol, but it's hard to say without more information).

Comment: Also: if you have access to an existing client that implements this protocol, you can capture packets between it and the server and see exactly how it's sending the data in question. A tool like tcpdump or Wireshark can help a lot here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example using a ByteBuffer.  Code is untested so make sure it works for you.

```
ByteBuffer bb = new ByteBuffer.allocate( 1024 );

short version = 0x0001;
short request = 0x0011;
int size = 0x08;

bb.order( ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN );
bb.put( version );
bb.put( request );
bb.put( size );

socket.getChannel().write( bb );
```