# Issues with converting from floating point little-endian to big-endian and back again

Tags: java, floating-point, endianness

I am trying to write a save parser which saves floating point numbers in little endian, however, Java is in big-endian, so i need to convert the FP and back again when writing but this does cause some inconsistencies on some floating point numbers.

I have tried reading in a floating point number, converting to int bits, reversing the int bits and then converting back to floating point.

and in reverse converting float to raw int bits, reversing the int bits, and then reconverting back to floating point.

```
    public void test()
    {
        //file contents (hex) 0x85, 0x76, 0x7e, 0xbd, 0x7f, 0xd8, 0xa8, 0x3e, 0x2f, 0xcb, 0x8f, 0x3d, 0x06, 0x7c, 0x70, 0x3f
        RandomAccessFile iRAF = new RandomAccessFile(new File("input.test"), "r");
        RandomAccessFile oRAF = new RandomAccessFile(new File("output.test"), "rw");

        byte[] input = new byte[16];
        iRAF.readFully(input);

        float[] floats = new float[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            floats[i] = readFloat(iRAF);
        }
        writeFloats(oRAF, floats);

        byte[] output = new byte[16];
        oRAF.seek(0);
        oRAF.readFully(output);

        if (Arrays.equals(input, output) == false)
        {
            System.err.println(toHex(input));
            System.err.println(toHex(output));
        }
    }

    private String toHex(byte[] bytes)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
        {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", bytes[i])).append(" ");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public float readFloat(RandomAccessFile raf) throws IOException
    {
        return Float.intBitsToFloat(Integer.reverseBytes(Float.floatToRawIntBits(raf.readFloat())));
    }

    public void writeFloats(RandomAccessFile raf, float... floats) throws IOException
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < floats.length; i++)
            raf.writeFloat(Float.intBitsToFloat(Integer.reverseBytes(Float.floatToRawIntBits(floats[i]))));
    }
```

I expect the output to have the exact same hex value as the input:

85 76 7e bd 7f **d8 a8 3e** 2f cb 8f 3d 06 7c 70 3f

but the actual output is:

85 76 7e bd 7f **c0 00 00** 2f cb 8f 3d 06 7c 70 3f

is this due to some floating point rounding error, or possibly when converting it's converting to a NaN value and not preserving the bits (although i would have thought this is what Float.floatToRawIntBits() is for.

Comment: Java is neither big endian nor little endian.  It depends on the hardware.  Have you looked at `ByteBuffer`?  It has a method to set the endian of the buffer (and thus all the data you put into it).

Comment: Here's an example of using `ByteBuffer`, let us know if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54542268/sending-a-byte-stream-from-a-java-program-to-a-device-running-c/54544160#54544160

Comment: @markspace it does work, however, it in most cases doubles or even triples the amount of time it takes to read the file (depending on the amount of floats in said file) (I am reusing the same byte buffer, not creating a new one each time)

Comment: That's odd.  ByteBuffers should be as fast or faster than other methods.  You might try posting the byte buffer code and ask why it takes so much longer.  Also: is your sole goal to copy the bytes?  Or do you intend to process these floats in some manner before sending them to the output file?

Comment: @markspace it is intended to edit parts of the file and rewrite it back, the byte buffer only correctly reads the float value if i read each byte into it which means reading 4 individual bytes, due to the api i am using, i can only read 1 byte or 1 float, no array of bytes as bytes are only used for null terminated strings.

Comment: Why do you use `Float.floatToRawIntBits(raf.readFloat())` rather than `raf.readInt()`?

Comment: Again, I'd post the working code with byte buffers, and ask why it might run so much slower than with `RandomAccessFile`.  You might be able to ask a specific question like that, rather than be sent off to the code review site (which fewer people read and answer at).  Worth a shot, but I can't guess why the byte buffer isn't working for you without some code.

Comment: @markspace the query from Patricia works, there is no need to use a byte buffer, but part of the original question still stands, why does one work and not the other, since they should be reversing methods and shouldn't modify the value.

Comment: @markspace Java is big-endian on any platform. See the Javadoc for `RandomAccessFile` and `Data/Input/OutputStream`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are encountering NaN collapsing. If you really need to distinguish different NaN values you are going to have more problems than just your file storage. According to the Java Language Specification, [4.2.3. Floating-Point Types, Formats, and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3):

> IEEE 754 allows multiple distinct NaN values for each of its single
>   and double floating-point formats. While each hardware architecture
>   returns a particular bit pattern for NaN when a new NaN is generated,
>   a programmer can also create NaNs with different bit patterns to
>   encode, for example, retrospective diagnostic information.
>
> For the most part, the Java SE Platform treats NaN values of a given
>   type as though collapsed into a single canonical value, and hence this
>   specification normally refers to an arbitrary NaN as though to a
>   canonical value.

I asked "Why do you use Float.floatToRawIntBits(raf.readFloat()) rather than raf.readInt()?" because I was trying to understand, and possibly simplify, your test program, not in any expectation of fixing the problem.